# Pass arguments to Python task in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running a script to which I want to add a parameter (here `-u` for unbuffered stdout). On local machine, I would just run `python -u script.py`.

Now, I want to run this Python script with unbuffered output on an Azure pipeline. Without unbuffered output, the task in my pipeline would be the following:

```
  - task: PythonScript@0

    displayName: 'Run script.py'
    inputs:
      scriptSource: filePath
      scriptPath: 'script.py'
      workingDirectory: 'myDir/'
```

**How can I add the `-u` (or any other) argument to Python command?** Is that possible with the "PythonScript" task at all?

I have tried to use `arguments` input, but that's obviously the arguments passed to my python script (e.g. after the "script.py" part). Also, tweaking somehow the `pythonInterpreter` input to "python.exe -u" to include the parameter, but the Python executable can't be found get recognised and the script won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way actually would be call it like a bash script:

```yaml
- bash: python -u myDir/script.py
  displayName: 'Run script.py'
```

Comment: Yes, looks like this is the only way. PythonScript task won't support it...